# Ref Spec for Branch Sources in Jenkins Job to build Master and all approved pull requests?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

What would be Ref Spec for Branch Sources to build Master and all approved pull requests?

I am trying something like this:

```
+refs/pull/${ghprbPullId}/*:refs/remotes/origin/pr/${ghprbPullId}/*
```

Comment: I am trying something like this : +refs/pull/${ghprbPullId}/*:refs/remotes/origin/pr/${ghprbPullId}/*